# Error to Install xdebug on Mac OS with php 8

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, xdebug

I just want to do `phpunit --coverage`for my project first I got this error:

```
PHPUnit 9.5.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Warning:       No code coverage driver available
```

I just check my php to make sure I have xdebug  via `php -v`

```
PHP 8.0.0 (cli) (built: Nov 30 2020 13:51:52) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.0-dev, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v8.0.0, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

seems I do not have it then I just install it via `pecl install xdebug` Homebrew I got this error at the end of installation:

```
........

Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/pecl/20200930/xdebug.so'

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in System.php on line 294

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/share/php/pear/System.php on line 294
ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/pecl/20200930
```

Comment: Please share more details. How is this problem related to Laravel or PHPUnit after all? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: Check `php -m` to find loaded modules, not `php -v`.

Comment: The provided solutions didn't work for me, I got it working as of 2023 04/01 here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75908035/1759443

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can step by step debug this problem with starting to check what it is inside the `/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1` folder running

```bash
$ cd /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1
$ ls -la
```

I tend to say that there is a `pecl` symlink already existing which is why `pecl` cannot create a folder there.

Then you should check where `pecl` is installed by running `which pecl` which ideally gives you `/usr/local/bin/pecl` which should point to somewhere `/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/bin/pecl`.

If that is the case you can remove the `/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/pecl` symlink with

```bash
$ rm /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/pecl
```

and try to reinstall xdebug.

**Now fixing the `image not found` issue**

This comes from an incorrect configuration during the xdebug installation.

First, check what the path to your `php.ini` file is by running `php --ini`.

Then open the file and check the First line if there is your xdebug Extension loaded. If yes, remove it there. Then add a file xdebug.ini in the `conf.d` folder and add the following to the file you create:

Xdebug version <3.0:

```
;XDebug
zend_extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0/pecl/CHANGEME/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp"
```

Xdebug version >=3.0

```
;XDebug
zend_extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0/pecl/CHANGEME/xdebug.so"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp"
```

Please check that you have the correct path to your xdebug.so file and that the output dir exists.

Comment: thank you so much I just remove the pecl then install it again it installed now, but I got weird error when I run `php -v`  : `Warning: Failed loading Zend extension 'xdebug.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20200930/xdebug.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20200930/xdebug.so, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20200930/xdebug.so.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20200930/xdebug.so.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 8.0.0 (cli) (built: Nov 30 2020 13:51:52) ( NTS )`

Comment: I updated my answer to describe the solution for your next problem

Comment: when I run `cd /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0/pecl` to make sure the folder number I got this `cd: no such file or directory: /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0/pecl` after some search I found `xdebug.so` in this path `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so` is that correct one?

Comment: This answer worked great. The only change I had to make was to make sure to name the xdebug.conf file with a .ini extension.

Comment: I also couldn't install xdebug with pecl because of the error in this post. 
And when I checked which pecl I had as advised in this answer, I found pecl in my php installation was not a symlink. 

I fixed this by uninstalling and installing php and then installing xdebug with pecl.

Comment: Finnaly a solution!, i need to put in the php.ini the complete path = extension = /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.2.7/pecl/20220829/imagick.so

and before i delete the symlink pecl of Cellar i found it with ls -la

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the symlink `rm /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.0.8_1` and then reinstalled the mongodb again `sudo pecl install mongodb`

[image]

But I still had the PHP Warning on loading the `mongodb.so` so I edited the php.ini file as below:

```
extension="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.0.8_1/pecl/20200930/mongodb.so"
```

Answer (score 0):

building on @codedge answer
you can add, to be able to use it in laravel
`xdebug.mode=coverage`
to the xdebug.ini file

Answer (score 0):

An update to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65836657/4568085

the "xdebug.ini" file options have been updated now the recommended settings are

```
;XDebug
zend_extension="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.1.9/pecl/20210902/xdebug.so"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_port=9003
;xdebug.mode=profile
xdebug.output_dir="/tmp"
```

The old options triggered warnings in PHP as shown below
[image: XDebug warnings]

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This is due to Xdebug 3. I updated my answer.