# Xdebug failed install on Mac m1

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm trying to install Xdebug on my Mac m1, I followed this page(https://xdebug.org/docs/install) to install. This is the step I followed:

step1 => go to cmd: arch -x86_64 sudo pecl install xdebug

step2 => go to php.ini delete this line of code

```
zend_extension="xdebug.so"
```

step3 => go to php.ini add this

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port="9003"
```

step4 => go to cmd: php -v

**The error shows:**

[image]

**How can I solve this problem? Thanks**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error to Install xdebug on Mac OS with php 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65834853/error-to-install-xdebug-on-mac-os-with-php-8)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What happened here is that you built a `x86_64` build of the extension, but homebrew likely used the `arm64e` architecture. These architectures are not compatible.

You can verify what your PHP's architecture is with:

```
file `which php`
```

If that says `arm64e`, then you need the original command from the documentation:

```
sudo pecl install xdebug
```

And if it's `x86_64`, then you need the command modified for Apple's dual architecture:

```
arch -x86_64 sudo pecl install xdebug
```

For what it's worth, the docs say: On Apple M1 hardware, you **might** instead need to use..., not **must**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, after I used file `which php`, its response Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64, so I need to use "sudo pecl install xdebug" to reinstall, the question is how do I uninstall the current xdebug? Thanks!!

Comment: @leojail You can run `sudo pecl install -f xdebug` to overwrite it, or run `sudo pecl uninstall xdebug` to remove it first.

Comment: I just ran into this error after trying this for a few hours. [This website](https://patriqueouimet.ca/tip/installing-php-and-pecl-extensions-on-macos) also helped me because of a pecl error

Comment: @Derick ideally you would like to install it in ARM archicture to gain from the performance benefits. is there any tracking solution here?

Comment: Make sure you uninstall the arm64e version first.   pecl uninstall xdebug

Answer (score 15):

### Solution for Macbook M1 as of 2023 07/01

1. `arch -arm64 pecl install xdebug`

- If `ERROR: failed to mkdir /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.2.4/pecl/20220829`, run `rm /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.2.4/pecl` then re-run above command

2. This will end successfully with a path. **Make note of it**, you'll need it soon:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.2.4/pecl/20220829/xdebug.so'
```

3. `php --ini`
4. Open the ini file shown: `open /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.2/php.ini`
5. Remove the first line (if it says something about xdebug)
6. Nav to conf.d directory (from php --ini) `cd /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.2/conf.d`
7. `touch xdebug.ini`
8. `open xdebug.ini`
9. Add the following code. **Edit extension path to be the one from step 2**

```
;XDebug
zend_extension="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.2.4/pecl/20220829/xdebug.so"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_port=9003
;xdebug.mode=profile
xdebug.output_dir="/tmp"
```

Running `php --version` should show you a line about xdebug (like so `with Xdebug v3.2.1`)

Answer (score 3):

If you encounter this:

- file `which php` result shows `Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64`.
- `sudo pecl install xdebug` still resulted in the wrong architecture
  problem.

Try this:

```
arch -arm64e sudo pecl install xdebug
```

Note: `arch -arm64` shown bad cpu type error in my case.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution now on M1

if `pecl install xdebug` doesn't work. run it with `sudo` command.
don't try the arch x84 command as it wont work anymore, since php is now build in arm cpu architecture.

Solution:

```
sudo pecl install xdebug
```